# Things disappearing with position:absolute but not position:relative?

Tags: html, css

On my background, whenever I set something to `position:absolute;` It disappears, but not when I set it to `position: relative;`

Any thoughts? Not really urgent, I can work with position relative, just curious. (Note: I know the picture has `style="display:none;"` in it but that doesn't matter, I change that with a function, so ignore it)

Picture:

```
<img src="http://i39.tinypic.com/15qvslj.jpg" style="top: 375px; left: 400px; position: relative; z-index: 1; visibility: show; display:none" id="Controls">
```

Background:
http://jsfiddle.net/vUN5A/

Comment: Added the code samples for you

Comment: It's the left: -400px

Comment: because of left: -400px;

Comment: @StepanParunashvili Don't answer the question in the comments - post it as an answer.

Comment: Gotcha winterblood, gave the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of

```
left: -400px;
```

it will position the object -400px left away from the viewport. try to use

```
left: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the `-400` was a typo, I changed it in your question for you.

You have a missing `;` in your style for the image. Change that, and then try to set the `display:none;` to `display:block;` and see if that changes anything.